# using ajax for real time update in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to create Create and Edit like facebook via ajax. ajax `scripts` is ready for me and `html` as below... but i dont know how make function for that.

`HTML & .JS` code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".editlink").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
  var dataset = $(this).prev(".datainfo");
  var savebtn = $(this).next(".savebtn");
  var theid   = dataset.attr("id");
  var newid   = theid+"-form";
  var currval = dataset.text();
  
  dataset.empty();
  
  $('<input type="text" name="'+newid+'" id="'+newid+'" value="'+currval+'" class="hlite">').appendTo(dataset);
  
  $(this).css("display", "none");
  savebtn.css("display", "block");
 });
 $(".savebtn").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var elink   = $(this).prev(".editlink");
  var dataset = elink.prev(".datainfo");
  var newid   = dataset.attr("id");
  
  var cinput  = "#"+newid+"-form";
  var einput  = $(cinput);
  var newval  = einput.attr("value");
  
  $(this).css("display", "none");
  einput.remove();
  dataset.html(newval);
  
  elink.css("display", "block");
 });
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
        <section id="core">
            <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top: 30px">

                <div class="gear">
                    <label>Primary E-Mail:</label>
                    <span id="pemail" class="datainfo">myaddress@googlemail.com</span>
                    <a href="#" class="editlink">Edit</a>
                    <button type="button" class="savebtn btn btn-primary btn-xs">Save</button>

                </div>

            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Controller:

```
\DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->update([
    [
        'email'      => $request->input('pemail'),
    ]
])->where('id', $id);
```

Comment: Have you simply tried achieving it? I mean, so far there seems to be no problem, just write down a simple ajax request to the server (or just a form submission) and then you can simply update your table using a model like this: `\App\User::find($id)->update(['fullname' => $request->input('pemail')]);` For that matter you'll have to have the `fullname` attribute added to the `protected $fillable` array of your model, take a look at the documentation about updating records and working with models.

Comment: I have already done this `fullname attribute added to the protected $fillable`

Comment: But that isn't the only thing to do tho, share your progress/efforts on the other part of the task.

Comment: i unable to understand what should i do in controller because this is ajax. i dont know that should it need `json` or anything. how to connect it with ajax code. @

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No need to use vue.js. Just use simple jQuery code as below. Hope it's
>   help.

**jQuery Code:**

```
Add event on save button On Click
onclick="saveProfile(INPUT ID HERE, RECORD ID)"
```

**Add jquery code in your footer or view file**

```
function saveProfile(id, inputid) {
    var value = $(inputid).val();
    $.ajax({
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
        url: "{{URL::to('admin/updateProfile')}}",
        data:{'id' : id,'value' : value,'inputid':inputid},
        method:'POST',
        success: function( resp ) {
            alert('update');                
        },
        error: function( req, status, err ) {
            console.log( 'something went wrong', status, err );
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller code**

```
public function updateProfile(REQUEST $request){
    $id = $request->id;
    $value = $request->value;
    $inputid = $request->inputid;
    //for examaple - Input textbox id is : pemail-form
    if($inputid == 'pemail-form'){
        DB::table('table_name')->where('id', $id)->update(['email' => $value]);
    }
    if($inputid == 'fullname-form'){
        DB::table('table_name')->where('id', $id)->update(['fullname' => $value]);
    }
}
```